# Unable to access static IP of wired device connected to wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, ethernet

I have a proprietary device with a static IP. I have connected this device to my wireless router through an ethernet cable. When I connect my laptop to the router via ethernet, I am able to access this static IP from my browser, but when I connect my laptop via wifi, I am unable to. Very weird. Someone help please.

Comment: What router do you have ?

Comment: Check what IP address you are getting when you connect to wired or wireless mode. If they belong to 2 different subnet then you can't reach each other.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the device to be accessed has a static IP, I assume you mean static within a subnetted LAN? That is with address 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.*? If so, perhaps your router maintains two separate networks, one for wired and one for wireless? Like 192.168.1.* and 192.168.0.*? This would give a level of separation from things which are known to be in your house (hardwired), and things which may be out on the street (wifi). Compare your laptops IP address when connected via ethernet to when it is connected wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information to fully diagnose the issue, but a couple things would prevent them from being able to talk, assuming that routing is set up correctly and the wireless network is in the same network.

First, the IP addresses must be in the same network.  The subnet mask determines the size of that network.  for example, given the address of 192.168.1.1 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, any IP in the range of 192.168.1.x (1-254) are in the same network.

Second, there must not be a duplicate IP.  Neither device will be able to communicate if they have the same address. The router/switch will not know which connection to send the communication signals.

Third, the address must be valid.  0-255 are the valid numbers, but the first and last are always used for network ID and broadcasting - for subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, you can use 1-254.  for a subnet mask of 255.255.255.128, you can use 1-126, or 129-254.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder what IP u r saying. Hope didnt get confused between internal and external IP.
Check ur external IP on both computers via www.whatsmyip.org , if they are not same can mean ur ISP allowed only one mac connection for static IP. Contact ur ISP about it or spoof ur laptops mac address. If that doesnt hrlp try digging in router and modem configuration page.